# how to put a picture between two textview?

Tags: android-layout

The two textviews are both wrap_content. and they will show dynamic characters. how can I put the picture between them. and make  the edge of picture have the same distance to both of them. I am a new of English and android developer. has anyone can understand me and do me a favor?  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To make the edge of picture have the same distance to two textviews, You can use the `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight`. Here is developer [link for LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear)

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end|right|center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text One"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Text Two"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Output for above code like below:

[image]

I hope this helps you